# Can I use System resources for Graphics instead of a graphics card?

Tags: graphics, resources, system

I'm not sure if this is the right place to post this question but I'm sure I will be told if it is wrong quick enough :-)

I have a amd fx-6100 with 16GB ram and a ati HD5450 2GB graphics card running windows7. I am finding that I can't play some of the newer PC games such as battlefield3 on my PC so the question is can I dedicate a core or two with a few GB of ram from the system resources to Graphics for playing games.

any help would be greatly appreciated or even a point in the right direction if this is the wrong place to ask this.

Comment: Yep, this question should probably be over on superuser.com instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GPU is faster then processors.  Thats why my friends PhD is on manipulating the GPU to start running more OS related stuff.  GFX cards are really good now, and to up the anty on them, as the human eye cant see more then whatever frames a second.  THey do well when they have to buffer like 5 things at once:  example, running 5 game clients + youtube + 1 movie.  All simultaneously.  Offloading from the GFX card to CPU is a no-no.  Now, if you have the money, get a nice 12 core gpu and then you wont have to worry about it.

tl;dr:  If you didnt know, gfx cards are faster then cpu.  It will only slow you if you want to do X-processor integration.  Doable, but you dont really gain anything worthwhile.  Get better gpu.

Comment: So there is no way of using unused system resources to help these games to play. Only get a better graphics card?

Comment: i dont think you should be needing it with a 2 gb graphics card.  What are you trying to play?  I know that I can run what i posted above, but if I play something like Skyrim, it will lock my pc and only refresh that game, and i am unable to multitask and play all the other things i normally do.  You can sort of do what you want, but the overhead cost isnt worth it.  It is a pain in the butt to do it, and there isnt (that i know of) a tool to do it for a easy fix.  I feel it might be something that would have to be handwritten based on a case to case scenerio.  I wish i knew more to help.

Comment: Sidenote:  When you use your processor more, and say, have it running at 100% use, to help this issue, it will start to freeze your computer a lot from all the page replacing to get the working set of the focused process, as it is working with less space. because it is pushed into your gpu.

Comment: When I play Assasins Creed II or BattleField 3 the game isn't smooth and the audio seems to be ahead of the visual. I think it is the speed of the porcessor on the graphics card rather than the 2gb Ram???